# mockito: WrongTypeOfReturnValue (JAVA)

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I've only recently started using Mockito (or mocking/stubbing for that matter).  I'm starting to get the hang on how to mock objects, but I'm stuck on the following code:

```
public class ConveyorBeltTest {
private Layout layout;
@Mock private WorkStation station1;
@Mock private WorkStation station2;
@Mock private WorkStation station3;
@Mock private CarAssemblyProcess car1;
@Mock private CarAssemblyProcess car2;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    layout = new Layout();
    layout.getWorkStations().add(station1);
    layout.getWorkStations().add(station2);
    layout.getWorkStations().add(station3);
    when(station1.retrievePendingTasks().size()).thenReturn(0);
    when(station2.retrievePendingTasks().size()).thenReturn(2);
    when(station3.retrievePendingTasks().size()).thenReturn(1);
    when(station1.getCar()).thenReturn(car1);
    // it's impossible to have a car in a workstation and to have pending tasks, but it's tested regardless
    when(station2.getCar()).thenReturn(car2);
    when(station3.getCar()).thenReturn(null);
}
```

The following line throws:

```
// line causing the problem
when(station1.retrievePendingTasks().size()).thenReturn(0);

// error msg
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Integer cannot be returned by retrievePendingTasks()
retrievePendingTasks() should return Set
```

It's obviously telling me that it can't recognize station1.retrievePendingTasks() because station1 is not a real object but a mock.  But I figured if I had a mock, I could chain commands behind the mock, which all wouldn't matter as long as I give the expected end result in thenReturn().  Can someone clarify what I did wrong here exactly?

I have also tried with:

```
doReturn(0).when(station1).retrievePendingTasks().size();
```

but the result is the same.

The workaround I have found is to make a new Set, fill it with mock elements and pass that to the result of retrievePendingTasks() for each station. This works, though that's quite a bit of extra code clogging up the screen when my only goal is to have a number for the size of the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're skipping over mocking what retrievePendingTasks returns and directly mocking what the thing returned by that method does. If you change the code to

```
when(station1.retrievePendingTasks()).thenReturn(new HashSet());
```

or something similar, then the size of the returned set will take care of itself.

If all you need is the size then you could make a mock implementation of the Set. Or you could use the deep stubs approach in [skegg99's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23698487/217324). Interestingly there's a caveat in the [API documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS):

> WARNING: This feature should rarely be required for regular clean code! Leave it for legacy code. Mocking a mock to return a mock, to return a mock, (...), to return something meaningful hints at violation of Law of Demeter or mocking a value object (a well known anti-pattern).

Mocking things that don't have dependencies, especially things like Java collections that are common building blocks, is usually unnecessary and will make your tests fragile. For instance here, if you change the code to determine the size some other way then your tests will break. if the code under test changes to use an iterator and doesn't test size directly then your test breaks. Or if there are other consequences of having an empty set then you'll have to mock those separately and end up doing a lot more work, and again risk breakage if the implementation changes. I try not to mock unnecessarily.

Comment: I have actually found a way to rewrite it without using mocks (mostly) :p  You're probably right that I should avoid mocks whenever I can. I only learned of this a day or two ago and got a bit carried away in excitement!  It's still useful to know for future situations.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: @Babyburger: getting carried away happens to us all. i have a codebase with a lot of mocking like that going on already.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's called deep stubs and required special care. You could use [this](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) approach and add

```
@Mock(answer=Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
```

But it's better to rewrite your tests to avoid it